# Windows XP installation loop and freeze

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation

I am trying to install Windows XP and I get to the first installation screen when it reboots and asks me to press any key.

- If I don't but just wait nothing happens.
- If I start installation again or *do* press a key it just starts all over again.

I tried a Windows 7 disc and that works fine although I don't have a spare product key so it has to be XP.

Any ideas?

Comment: More information is required to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the CD
2. press *any* key
3. it should boot from the partly installed winXP
4. after it boots into the 2nd part of the installer, reinsert the CD

good luck.

Comment: Or just ignore the "Press any key to boot from CD..." prompt from the XP install disc's bootloader. After a few seconds, it'll boot from the hard disk into stage 2 install.

Comment: @AaronMiller: maybe, but not necessarely. He seems to boot into the installer anyway, there's the possibility he doesn't press a key so this would be 'bulletproof' :P

Comment: I do not press any key although I wait for several minuites and nothing happends, I don't think it should take that long. When I take the disc out it just flashes like a command prompt

Comment: can you boot with the CD out if you press some keys?

Comment: If the CD is out I just get a command prompt like screen with a text line flashing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I had an 500GB hard drive I created two partitions. The OS went on a 70GB partition and it worked